# Excel query automation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on automation with Python. In one step, I need to take a column and check that only the required values are in the sheet. (We use filter in Excel and select the required values.)

What function in pandas can help me?

Comment: Use the logical indexing capabilities of pandas: `df[df['MY_COL']=='foo']`

Comment: This might be helpful as well:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas to achieve any tasks with a table.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('myexcelfile.xlsx')
    df.filter(items=['one', 'three'])
```

for more on filter refrer [pandas filter]:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Comment: `filter` method only selects whole columns or rows not based on values within.